# Group 2 similar requests Entity Framework / Linq in 1

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have 2 views SQL Server with the same columns.
I have 2 linq requests with Entity Framework exactly the same ; one applied to the View1, the other on the View2.
I want to group the 2 request in one only call.

```
switch (day) {
    case day == MONDAY:
        List<int> results = (from day in **container.View1**
                             join model in container.OtherTable ...
                             where ... 
                             ...
                             select id).ToList();
        break;
    case day == FRIDAY:
        List<int> results = (from day in **container.View2**
                             join model in container.OtherTable ...
                             where ... 
                             ...
                             select id).ToList();
        break;
}
```

I would like something like

```
ObjectSet<EntityObject> cont= null;

switch (day) {
    case day == MONDAY:
        cont = container.View1;
        break;
    case day == FRIDAY:
        cont = container.View2;
        break;
}

List<int> results = (from day in **cont**
                     join model in container.OtherTable ...
                     where ... 
                     ...
                     select id).ToList();
```

to optimize the code but I don't know how to group this code like that...

Comment: Are you asking how to request from both tables at the same time, with results from both tables concatenated, or are you trying to query just one (dynamically selected) table?

Comment: The second point :) ; I try to query just one selected dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Have all the different views you want to select from implement the same Interface and do something like:

```
public class Something {
    public List<int> GetSomething(Day day)
    {
        var dbc = new Context();

        switch (day)
        {  
            case MONDAY: return  GetResult(dbc.table1, dbc );
            case FRIDAY: return  GetResult(dbc.table2, dbc);
        }
    }

    public List<int> GetResult<T>(DbSet<T> table, Context context) where T : class, MyInterface
    {
        List<int> results = (from day in table
                    join model in context.OtherTable on day.Id equals model.dayId
                    select day.Id).ToList();
        return results;
    }
}

public interface MyInterface
{
        int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**: As for your comment, create an interface like the one above, and have your entities implement it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just a problem with the solution.
The Views generated by EF4 contains some attribute like `public int id;`
I need like you suggest these views implement _MyInterface_ and this interface need the same attribute `public int id;`. 
But I don't know how to implement correctly the interface in order to the `select id`in linq be considered.

Comment: i updated my answer with code for the required interface.